# TFS 2012 Change Process Template

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfs-process-template, agile-processes

Is there a way to migrate from MSF Agile 6.0 to a Scrum process template in TFS 2012? We have migrated from TFS 2010 to 2012 recently and would like to change the process template without loosing history.

I've heard about http://witsynchronizer.codeplex.com/ but has anyone tried it for TFS 2012?

Comment: Archive and migrate the code to a new team project is the easiest and least time intensive method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way in which we have done this is;

1. In Visual Studio (I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2012) Go to Team Explorer - Home (Make sure you are in the correct collection / project)
2. In the drop down menu navigate to Projects & My Team & Select New Team Project
3. Enter your desired team project name and description
4. Select the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.0 - Preview 4 process template
5. Configure the SharePoint site if you wish but we choose "Do not configure the SharePoint site at this time"
6. Specify Source Control Settings - We choose "Create a new source control branch" and select the area of code we want to branch from. This then should retain all of your history.
7. Confirm your team project settings and then click Finish.

Hope this helps, it may not be the correct way but works for us.